# MySQL How to use substract among sum

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I have table with columns "Rank (like ID)", "Latitude","Longitude". Now my select works like that:

```
Rank Latitude  Longitude Latitude_current_row_plus_next  Longitude_current_row_plus_next
1      5          3           11   --5+6                          7 --3+4      
2      6          4           7    --6+1                          6 --4+2
3      1          2           6    --1+5                          7 --2+5
4      5          5           ..                                  ..
..    ..         ..           ..                                  ..
```

what do i expect to get:

```
Rank Latitude  Longitude Latitude_current_row_minus_next  Longitude_current_row_minus_next
1      5          3           1  --abs(5-6)                       1 --abs(3-4)  
2      6          4           5  --abs(6-1)                       2 --abs(4-2)
3      1          2           4  --abs(1-5)                       3 --abs(2-5)
4      5          5           ..                                  ..
..    ..         ..           ..                                  ..
```

How to change the code to use subtraction instead of sum?

I need to subtract the value of the next line from the current value. And then add ABS function to result

```
SELECT   a.rank,a.latitude,a.longitude,
(SELECT SUM(latitude) FROM temp 
 WHERE rank <= a.rank + 1 AND rank >= a.rank) as latitude_current_row_plus_next,
(SELECT SUM(longitude) FROM temp
 WHERE rank <= a.rank+1 AND rank >= a.rank) as longitude_current_row_plus_next 
FROM temp a;
```

Thank you for anyone.

Comment: While not entirely incorrect, GL's statement is a little inaccurate... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead

Comment: @Strawberry I am using MySQL 5.6, so i can't use lead/lag functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `lead()` function, but that is not available in MySQL.

I would recommend using `left join`:

```
select t.*,
       abs(t.latitude - tnext.latitude) as lat_diff,
       abs(t.longitude - tnext.longitude) as lng_diff
from temp t left join
     temp tnext
     on t.rank = tnext.rank - 1;
```